# Is it possible at this moment to create backend in Swift?

Tags: swift, backend

I'm going to create a web application. I wonder if it is possible at this moment to create it in Swift? I have found some information on the web (for instance server-side Swift - Perfect) but I'm not sure whether it is sufficiently developed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: On what system will you be running it? Linux or macOS?

Comment: I use macOS Sierra.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. For instance [Perfect](https://www.perfect.org/) is a webserver and toolkit that runs Swift.

Answer (score 3):

There are some frameworks for that (alphabetically sorted):

- [Kitura](https://github.com/IBM-Swift/Kitura)
- [Perfect](https://github.com/PerfectlySoft/Perfect)
- [Vapor](https://github.com/vapor/vapor)
- [Zewo](https://github.com/Zewo/Zewo)

Which one is better (best) is debatable (and not a valid question for SO anyway).  But to answer your question, yes, this is possible.  Each of the above frameworks has a slack channel where you can ask around about details.

**[UPD]**

As of yesterday, there is even a dedicated [Server APIs Work Group](https://swift.org/blog/server-api-workgroup/).